# Why does airnav list frequencies for some STARs on the airport info page?

Tags: air-traffic-control, tracon, frequency

I was on airnav.com and looked up [the info for KIWA](http://www.airnav.com/airport/KIWA). Why does airnav list frequencies for the arrivals (STARs) that serve an airport? Does each frequency correspond to a certain TRACON sector?

Comment: They look like the same frequencies that are printed on the STAR charts themselves: 120.7 for DSERT, 124.1 for BLYTHE, etc...